# Firebase retrival, getChildren vs getValue multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is whether it is more efficient to getChildren in a query and then have all your if else statements sorting the data
Or whether it would be better to have multiple calls to the database which are obviously already sorted?

I would assume getting the children would be better since you are only making one call to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is whether it is more efficient to getChildren in a query and then have all your if-else statements sorting the data Or whether it would be better to have multiple queries which are obviously already sorted?

Reading all the data within a node at once sounds not as a good solution to go ahead with. When you attach a listener on such a reference, you are reading all direct children that exist beneath that node, including the nested ones. Filtering the results on the client might be considered a waste of bandwidth and resources.

Suppose you have a node with 1000 objects and you are looking for only three of them. Imagine what would be the size of the result set when getting all 1000 objects? I can imagine that it will be huge. So the best option that you have is to use a query a do the filtering directly on the server. In this manner, the size of the result set will be very small, because only three elements will be returned and **not** 1000. So basically you are getting only the results you are interested in.

> I would assume getting the children would be better since you are only making one call to the database?

That's actually the opposite. There nothing wrong in creating multiple Firebase database calls.

Comment: May I add, you can also use pagination in case the user wants more data.

Comment: @Walid Implementing pagination it's always a good approach.